# How to get Multiple Information using | grep?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, grep

I want to extract multiple information using grep.
example:

when using *exiftool*, I got all this information, and more:

```
$exiftool Titanic.Avi

ExifTool Version Number         : 8.60
File Name                       : Titanic.Avi
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 702 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:07:28 22:36:46+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : AVI
```

1. I want to view only the File Name and the File Type.

like this:

```
File Name                       : Titanic.Avi
File Type                       : AVI
```

I have a Directory Movie, and containing a hole directories, in each directory there is a movie, i want to extract those information from it

example:

```
Movies\Titanic\Titanic.avi
Movies\The Call\The Call.avi
.
.
Movies\Pawn\Pawn.mkv
```

1. I need a loop with *exiftool* and | grep to get info like this:

Titanic.avi

```
File Name                       : Titanic.Avi
File Type                       : AVI
```

The Call.avi

```
    File Name                       : The Call.Avi
    File Type                       : AVI
```

Pawn.mkv

```
    File Name                       : Pawn.Avi
    File Type                       : MKV
```

Comment: consider using the command line tool to actively query for the specific information you wanted, instead of using grep: http://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```
function identify()
{
    for fname in "$@"
    do
        while read line
        do
           echo "$fname $line"
        done < <(exiftool "$1"|egrep 'File Type|File Name')
    done
}
```

Now you can

```
identify *.mkv *.avi
```

<strike>(note untested: I don't have these tools or any sample files available)</strike>Update. Just tested by making a dummy helper

```
function exiftool() { echo File Type 5; echo 42 File Name; }
identify *
```

If you wanted all information for a file on one line, you could add `xargs`:

```
exiftool "$1"|egrep 'File Type|File Name' | xargs
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at mediainfo, you can directly use it to get particular metadata.

```
mediainfo --Inform='General;%CompleteName% - %Format%' Du.Plo*    

=> Du.Plomb.Dans.La.Tete.2012.VOSTFR.REPACK.720p.BluRay.x264-Felony.mkv - Matroska
```